# Unable to combine tags using TagBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I'm trying to build a combination tag:

First tag: `<span class="requiredInidicator">* </span>`
Second tag: `<label>SomeText</label>` (Attributes snipped for brevity)

I would like to combine these to return an MVCHtmlString but the following code ignores the span completely. Could someone point out
what I am doing wrong

Here is my code:

```
// Create the Label
var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("id", "required" + id);
//I get the id earlier fyi - not pertinent fyi for this question )

// Create the Span
var required = new TagBuilder("span");
required.AddCssClass("requiredInidicator"); 
required.SetInnerText("* ");

//Now combine the span's content with the label tag
tagBuilder.InnerHtml += required.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
tagBuilder.SetInnerText(labelText);
var tag = MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
return tag;
```

When the tag is created, the *span* is ignored completely. When I inspect the tag during debug, it doesn't care about the required that I appended via `.InnerHtml+=`

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var label = new TagBuilder("label");
label.Attributes.Add("id", "required" + id);
//I get the id earlier fyi - not pertinent fyi for this question )

// Create the Span
var span = new TagBuilder("span");
span.AddCssClass("requiredInidicator");
span.SetInnerText("* ");

//Now combine the span's content with the label tag
label.InnerHtml = span.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + htmlHelper.Encode(labelText);
return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be calling `SetInnertext` (especially after having just assigned `Innerhtml`). You want to use one or the other.

if you're looking to append, keep going with `InnerHtml += labeltext`.

Comment: The difference being that SetInnerText Html encodes the string, where InnerHtml does not.

Answer (score 2):

You could always do:

```
string output = "";
output += tabBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
output += required.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

return MvcHtmlString.Create(output);
```

The issue could be the TagBuilder assumes one root level HTML tag, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
tagBuilder.SetInnerText(labelText + required.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the InneHtml property on the span

```
// Create the Span
var required = new TagBuilder("span");
required.InnerHtml ("SOME TEXT");
```