# MVC html Custom helper for a status inidicator

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to create a server status icon on the top of my application. When it is off appear as red, and on the other hand when it is on appear as green.

I have done all the dirty job in my DAL, BL, Controller and ViewModel and as a result i have a div element on my page which change colors subjected on the service status. My problem is that i cannot add a label next to the div.

```
public static class ServerStatusIconHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ServerStatusIconHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool isServerActive)
    {
        // Main container
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        bool isActive = isServerActive;
        var labelValue = isActive ? "The server status is On" : "The server status is Off";

        if (isActive)
        {
            div.Attributes.Add("id", "server-warning-on");
            div.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: green; height:25px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 25px; width: 25px; margin-left: 10px;");
        }
        else
        {
            div.Attributes.Add("id", "server-warning-off");
            div.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red; height:25px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 25px; width: 25px; margin-left: 10px;");
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(div.ToString());
    }
}
```

I would appreciate some help since i dont know to add a div with a paragraph element which will provide the `labelValue`. In addition if anyone has any idea for something better would be nice.

Comment: You didn't set any inner text or inner html for div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`TagBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder(v=vs.111).aspx) you can set tag content using `InnerHtml` property or `SetInnerText` method:

- [`InnerHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.innerhtml(v=vs.111).aspx): Gets or sets the inner HTML value for the element.
- [`SetInnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.setinnertext(v=vs.111).aspx): Sets the InnerHtml property of the element to an HTML-encoded version of the specified string.

Here is an example:

```
var div = new TagBuilder("div");
div.AddCssClass("someClass");
div.MergeAttribute("id", "someId");
div.InnerHtml = "Some Text or Html Tag";
var result=  div.ToString();
```

Which generates this output:

```
<div class="someClass" id="someId">Some Text or Html Tag</div>
```

Comment: at the moment i have done some progress and i am almost done. I made some additions span.SetInnerText(labelValue);
            div.InnerHtml = labelValue;

Answer (score 0):

You can combine label and div tags [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13747072/2878684).

Also, you need to add `display: inline-block;` to your style to display label next to div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InnerHtml` property of the tag.

```
var labelValue = isActive ? "The server status is On" : "The server status is Off";
div.InnerHtml = labelValue;
```

or if you want to concatenate a `span` element with div, you can do

```
var span = new TagBuilder("span");
span.InnerHtml = labelValue;
```

and return as

```
return new MvcHtmlString(div.ToString() + span.ToString());
```